# Is it possible to issue a spatial join with shapes from two tables?

Tags: sql, join, spatial, crate

I want to be able to run a query like:

```
select A.*
  from A
  join B
    on match(A.geom,B.wkt) using within;
```

But i get:

```
ERROR:  UnhandledServerException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: queryTerm must be a literal
```

Sample schema:

```
create table if not exists A (
  id integer,
  geom geo_shape
);

create table if not exists B (
  id integer,
  wkt string index off
);
```

The reason for trying `wkt string` is due to the [documentation's use of WKT literals](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/geo.html#match-predicate). Additionally, since our actual implementation is a variable number of geometries that we might join against and `geo_shape` can't exist in an object, we were hoping to WKT would work with a join.

**Update 1** (per [Augmented Jacob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41289902/23056)) Trying geo_shape join geo_shape with this schema:

```
create table if not exists B (
  id integer,
  wkt geo_shape
);
```

And the above query produces a different error:

```
SQLParseException: Couldn't create executionContexts from NodeOperations
... original-error: Can't handle Symbol io.crate.analyze.symbol.MatchPredicate@6666c921
```

And, while the error isn't ideal, I wouldn't expect it to work anyway since the [docs state](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/geo.html#match-predicate):

> Note
>
> One MATCH predicate cannot combine columns of both relations of a join.

**Update 2** With geo_shape join geo_shape, `match` doesn't work but `within` works, though, [being "exact" queries](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/geo.html#exact-queries), the performance makes it mostly unusable, at least across our 2.4B rows.

```
select A.*
  from A
  join B
    on within(B.wkt,A.geom);
```

Comment: Hi, do you also have a table schema handy? This is something that could also be a bug :)

Comment: @claus Updated with an example of the schema.

Comment: BTW, I think there are multiple errors depend on whether and how the query uses `on` and `where`. But, so far, I've had no success with any combination of clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `match` predicate Crate leverages the generated Lucene index of the `geo_shape` to get really fast but not "exact" results (as you already noticed). However, a geospatial match on two relations (join) is not possible with Lucene and that is why Crate is not able to do it. The documentation explains it also here:
https://crate.io/docs/reference/en/latest/sql/joins.html#join-conditions

Answer (score 0):

Your Variable in Table A `geom` is of type `geo_shape` whereas B has `wkt` of type `string`.

Change them to matching types and it should solve your `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: That was my first try but it errors `SQLParseException: Couldn't create executionContexts from
NodeOperations ... original-error: Can't handle Symbol io.crate.analyze.symbol.MatchPredicate@6666c921` So i reverted to trying WKT because that's [the required literal](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/geo.html#match-predicate).